# Help me with this recursive combinatorial algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, pseudocode

Folks,
I have N bounded sets:

```
S1 = {s11, s12, ... s1a }
S2 = {s21, s22, ... s2b }
...
sN=  {sN1, sN2, ... sNx }
```

I have a function f() that takes one argument A from each set:

```
f( A1, A2, ... AN ) such that Ax belongs to Sx
```

I need to invoke f() for all possible combinations of arguments:

```
f( s11, s21, ... sN1 )
f( s11, s21, ... sN2 )
f( s11, s21, ... sN3 )
...
f( s11, s21, ... sNx )
...
f( s1a, s2b, ... sNx )
```

Can someone help me figure out a recursive (or iterative) algorithm that will hit all combinations?

Thanks in advance.

-Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically you want to generate the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) `s1 x s2 x ... x sN`.

This is a classic application of backtracking / recursion. Here's how a pseudocode would look like:

```
function CartesianProduct(current, k)
    if (k == N + 1)
        current is one possibility, so call f(current[1], current[2], ..., current[N])
        and return

    for each element e in Sk
        call CartesianProduct(current + {e}, k + 1)

Initial call is CartesianProduct({}, 1)
```

You should write it on paper and see how it works. For example, consider the sets:

```
s1 = {1, 2}
s2 = {3, 4}
s3 = {5, 6}
```

The first call will be `CartesianProduct({}, 1)`, which will then start iterating over the elements in the first set. The first recursive call with thus be `CartesianProduct({1}, 2)`. This will go on in the same manner, eventually reaching `CartesianProduct({1, 3, 5}, 4)`, for which the termination condition will be true (`current.Length == N + 1`). Then it will backtrack and call `CartesianProduct({1, 3, 6}, 4)` and so on, until all possibilities are generated. Run it on paper all the way to see exactly how it works.
A

**Extra credit**: can you figure out how to get rid of the `k` parameter?